# Accessing this.context from onSubmitSuccess of redux-form

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux-form

Here is the problem I am facing:

I am using react-router and redux-form in my application. In one of my forms, I want to use the router to go back to the main page after the submission succeeds. Here is the code I have:

```js
function Router(target) {
  target.contextTypes = target.contextTypes || {};
  target.contextTypes.router = React.PropTypes.func.isRequired;
}

enter code here
@Router
@reduxForm({
    form: 'editLocation',
    fields: LocationFormFields,
    validate: ValidateLocationForm,
    onSubmitSuccess: () => {
        var path = '/locations';
        this.context.router.push(path);
    },
    onSubmitFail: () => {
        console.log('failed');
    }
}, MapStateToProps)
export class EditLocation extends React.Component .....
```

The problem is that 'this.context' is not defined inside the onSubmitSucess method.

I know that I can take care of this using browserHistory directly. However, I don't want to really go that route and I want to use this.cotext. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet is to not make your form component the same as your route component, and pass in the `onSubmitSuccess` as a prop to your form component.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

@withRouter // injects router as prop
export class EditLocation extends React.Component {

  handleSubmitSuccess() {
    this.props.router.push('/locations')
  }

  render() {
    return <EditLocationForm
      onSubmitSuccess={this.handleSubmitSuccess}/>
  }      
}

@reduxForm({
    form: 'editLocation',
    fields: LocationFormFields,
    validate: ValidateLocationForm,
    onSubmitFail: () => {
        console.log('failed');
    }
}, MapStateToProps)
export class EditLocationForm extends React.Component .....
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Erik.  This sounds like it will work based on this note in the documentation: http://redux-form.com/6.0.1/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/  "IMPORTANT: All of these configuration options may be passed into reduxForm() at "design time" or passed in as props to your component at runtime."

Answer (score 0):

To use `context` inside a component you need to specify `contextTypes`

```
static contextTypes = {
   router: PropTypes.object
};
```

So I would recommend either to call you function from inside the component and specify `contextTypes` there or add one higher order component to handle that.

Comment: No, that function isn't bound to any `this`, so that won't help.